# how to play sound in specific times?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

> hi i had android app which play sound when value on i did my code well and it worked well .
> I need to make as list or array or whatever have specific days with
> times as :
>
> **day** 07.07.1013
>
> **times** 3.30pm , 1.20am ,3.30am ....etc.

as when the day 07.07.2013 and the o'clock 1.20am the sound play . how to do that ?

```
 @JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value  ) {
    
    if (value.equals("on")){
        checked = true;
       
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  
        checked = false;
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AlarmManager to set an alarm for that time.  When the alarm comes in, play the sound.

Comment: If you're a beginner you'll learn a lot by reading the AlarmManager docs and asking questions until it makes sense.